# Can you store functions as fields in a struct? How to store instructions?

Tags: rust

In my model, I have a Petgraph graph which stores as nodes a struct with fields as followed:

```
struct ControlBloc
{
    name:String,
    message_inbox:Vec<MessageObj>,
    blocked:bool,
    instruct:String,
    inbox_capacity:f64,
    buffer:Vec<MessageObj>,
    number_discarded:u32,
    clock_queue:SendingQueue,
    clock_speed:f64,
}
```

In it there is a field called `instruct` in which I want to store instructions. I want to code the model in a way such that after some time, all the nodes will execute the instructions that are stored in the struct. Instructions can be for example send messages to other nodes, computing something... I want something versatile.

Is there a way to store functions as fields in a struct? and then after some time, the function stored can be called and whatever function will be executed?

One way that I see doing this is maybe using `enum` to store all the function names then using a function to map whatever enum to the corresponding function, for example:

```
enum FuncName {
    SendMessage,
    ComputeSize,
    StoreSomething,
    DoNothing,
}

fn exec_function(func:FuncName)
{
    match func {
        FuncName::SendMessage => send_message_function(input1,input2),
        FuncName::ComputeSize => compute_size_function(input1,input2,input3),
        FuncName::StoreSomething => store_something_funtion(input1),
        FuncName::DoNothing => (),
    }
}
```

However in this case you can't really customize the inputs of the `FuncName` function and they either have to be always preset to the same thing or in the input of `exec_function` you add all the different inputs fields of all the functions in `FuncName` but that seems rather overkill, even then, I dont really see how to pass them and store in the struct.

Is there then a way to directly add the functions or something in the struct? I know I'm breaking many Rust rules but say for example I had a variable already declared `let bloc = ControlBloc::new(...);` then you could set the function as for example `bloc.instruct = send_message_function(node1,node2);` and then when you called `bloc.instruct` then that would call whatever function is stored there.

Is something like this possible or am I dreaming or like very difficult (I am still learning the language)?

Comment: Are you asking about `Box<MyFunc>` where `MyFunc` is your own custom trait? That for example exposes `Call()` method? You could of course store raw function pointers, but that's less flexible.

Comment: Where do `inputN` come from?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html?highlight=function%20pointer

Comment: @freakish do you have any ressources I could ook at? I've tried researching Box<MyFunc> but didn't find anything

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Are you talking about the inputs of the exec_function? I suppose they would be predefined when creating the exec_function but it wouldn't enable me to change them as I wish

Comment: This is the question; do you want to provide them when you store the function or when you call the stored function?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I want to provide them when I store he function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is store `Box<dyn Fn()>` in your struct:

```
struct Foo {
    instruct: Box<dyn Fn(Vec<i32>)>
}

fn sum(vec: Vec<i32>) {
    let sum: i32 = vec.into_iter().sum();
    println!("{}", sum);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        instruct: Box::new(|vec| {
            let sum: i32 = vec.into_iter().sum();
            println!("{}", sum);
        })
    };

    (foo.instruct)(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);

    let foo = Foo {
        instruct: Box::new(sum)
    };

    (foo.instruct)(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
}
```

`Fn` is implemented automatically by closures, which only take immutable references to captured variables or don’t capture anything at all, as well as (safe) function pointers (with some caveats, see their documentation for more details). Additionally, for any type F that implements Fn, &F implements Fn, too.

#EDIT

In my example I used `Vec<i32>` as an abstract for multiple arguments. However if you are going to have some set of instructions that have different count of arguments, but within itself always the same, consider creating a trait `Instruct` and create struct for every different instruct that will implement this.

[Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b?code=%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0A%0A*%2F%0Astruct%20Foo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20instruct%3A%20Box%3Cdyn%20Instruct%3CT%3E%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20Instruct%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run(%26self)%20-%3E%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo%20%3D%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instruct%3A%20Box%3A%3Anew(CalcSum%3A%3Anew(vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20(foo.instruct).run())%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20bar%20%3D%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instruct%3A%20Box%3A%3Anew(PrintStrings%3A%3Anew(String%3A%3Afrom(%22Peter%22)%2C%20String%3A%3Afrom(%22Paul%22)))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20(bar.instruct).run()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20CalcSum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20f%3A%20Box%3Cdyn%20Fn()%20-%3E%20i32%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20CalcSum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new(arg%3A%20Vec%3Ci32%3E)%20-%3E%20CalcSum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CalcSum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%3A%20Box%3A%3Anew(move%20%7C%7C%20arg.iter().sum%3A%3A%3Ci32%3E())%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Instruct%3Ci32%3E%20for%20CalcSum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run(%26self)%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(self.f)()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20PrintStrings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20f%3A%20Box%3Cdyn%20Fn()%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20PrintStrings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new(s1%3A%20String%2C%20s2%3A%20String)%20-%3E%20PrintStrings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PrintStrings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%3A%20Box%3A%3Anew(move%20%7C%7C%20println!(%22%7B%7D%20and%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20s1%2C%20s2))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Instruct%3C()%3E%20for%20PrintStrings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(self.f)()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A)

```
struct Foo<T> {
    instruct: Box<dyn Instruct<T>>
}

trait Instruct<T> {
    fn run(&self) -> T;
}

struct CalcSum {
    f: Box<dyn Fn() -> i32>
}

impl CalcSum {
    fn new(arg: Vec<i32>) -> CalcSum {
        CalcSum {
            f: Box::new(move || arg.iter().sum::<i32>()),
        }
    }
}

impl Instruct<i32> for CalcSum {
    fn run(&self) -> i32 {
        (self.f)()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, some of the other comments mentioned Box but I haven't been able to find an implementation of my problem, this really helped with my beginner understanding of Rust, thank you!

Comment: The reason for using Box here is that Instruct is going to be some struct that implements Instruct so it's not known at compile time what's size it's going to have (this goes to Fn() as well). Rust needs to know it, because it has to allocate memory for them and needs to know how much. Box is a pointer, `smart pointer` to be precise, it has always the same size so that's why it solves the problem. You should find this chapter very helpful: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html